# Where do you keep your common sql task scripts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, scripting

In your workplace, where do you store your common, non-database specific scripts that you use in SQL Server? Do you keep them in .SQL scripts on the file server, do you store them in the Master database, or do you keep them in a database you defined specifically for these kinds of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We store them as regular source code, so in version-control.
You have then available previous versions of script, and you avoid "someone deleted the XY script" risk.

Comment: How do you access them in Mgt. Studio? Do you have them setup as a project?

Comment: No, we don't use projects in management studio. All "structures" are set in directory hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

We store them in a wiki where everyone can access them.

Answer (score 1):

We store them in a separate database and have a custom program for easy execution and maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I horde them all in [template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174169.aspx) format on my hard drive.  CTRL+SHIFT+M will fill the placehoders.  It's great.